# Form submit event defined with Drupal.behaviors fires several times

Tags: 8, javascript

I want to react in JavaScript on the submission of a form but whatever I try the function is called three times:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.xmasEasteregg = {
    attach: function attach(context) {
      $(document).on('submit', '#aw-search-form', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var input_field = $(this).find('#edit-search-keys'),
          search_value = input_field.val();
        alert(search_value);
      });
    }
  }
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

When I do it this way the alert is shown only once:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  $(document).on('submit', '#aw-search-form', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var input_field = $(this).find('#edit-search-keys'),
      search_value = input_field.val();
    alert(search_value);
  });
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Maybe I do misunderstand about JavaScript and Drupal.behaviors. My aim is that this logic is working on elements which were created / inserted by Ajax - which I think the first code assures?

Comment: Isn't that a job for [`.once()`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview#s-drupalbehaviors)?